# UNIX_TIMESTAMP returning NULL on dates having years older than 1970

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I am using the SQL `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` function get the UNIX_TIMESTAMP of dates stored in a table in `datetime` data type. I started getting weird results. Further troubleshooting shows that, all dates beyond 1970 are returning `NULL`

How do I get around this?

Test SQL statement:

```
SELECT userId, dateValue, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(dateValue) FROM ow_base_question_data WHERE `questionName` = 'birthdate'
```

The result is in the image below.

[image: SQL query result]

Answer (score 4):

The `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` started on 00:00:00 1 January 1970. So older dates than this will return `null`. Because of the counting starting at 00:00:00 1 January 1970.

More info:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time

Comment: Okay thanks. Any way to get around this? How do I get dates older than 1970 in UNIX_TIMESTAMP in SQL?

Comment: You can't! UNIX_TIMESTAMP  started at 1 January 1970, So you can't go older, because it's not counted